# How to quickly search for public methods of a class in python

Tags: python

I used to program in Java and one good thing about Java is that it is always easy to find out what class type is an object and I am used to the Java API document format to browse through methods provided by a class. This is an advantage when I face a new third party package.

However, when I learn python, one thing that frustrates me is it is not easy to quick see (without writing extra code) what class type is an object (especially for an object that is returned from a chain of methods) and the API documents lack the consistency comparing to Java. So I have more difficulty when picking up a new package in python than in Java.

Am I missing any tricks or principles in python or what? How does everyone do when picking up a new package to use? Many thanks for any guides.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things that I find useful when working with a new library.

You can use the `type()` function to see the class or type of an unknown object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> n = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(n)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

If you would like to know which methods and attributes an object has you can use the `dir()` function:

```
>>> dir(n)
['__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__radd__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', 'astimezone', 'combine', 'ctime', 'date', 'day', 'dst', 'fromordinal', 'fromtimestamp', 'hour', 'isocalendar', 'isoformat', 'isoweekday', 'max', 'microsecond', 'min', 'minute', 'month', 'now', 'replace', 'resolution', 'second', 'strftime', 'strptime', 'time', 'timetuple', 'timetz', 'today', 'toordinal', 'tzinfo', 'tzname', 'utcfromtimestamp', 'utcnow', 'utcoffset', 'utctimetuple', 'weekday', 'year']
```

You can use the `help()` function in a python console to see the help text for a module or function:

```
>>> help(n.isocalendar)
Help on built-in function isocalendar:

isocalendar(...)
    Return a 3-tuple containing ISO year, week number, and weekday.
```

Hope that helps!